# how to share data between two component using Event Emitter?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

Could you please suggest how to add item in list when something enter in input field and then `enter` press.But these are different component .I want to share input field value to different component using @Input ,@Output ,EventEmitter.

I make one component .
`<todo></todo`>

here is ts file

```
import { Page,NavController,Modal } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';



@Component({
  selector:'todo'
  templateUrl:"addtodo.html",
})
export class AddToDO{

constructor() {

    }
    addItem(v){
     alert(v.value)
    }
}
```

here is my html

```
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label" >Add Todo</span>
  <input type="text" #todo placeholder="Add todo" (keyup.enter)="addItem(todo)">
</label>
```

I want to add item list when enter is press .so need to share data between component

http://plnkr.co/edit/N6aXDZXUr99MC6w77H6d?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage an `@Output` in your `AddToDO` component to trigger that an element was added. So you can catch it from the parent component and add the corresponding data in the list.

```
@Component({
  selector:'todo'
  templateUrl:"addtodo.html",
})
export class AddToDO{
  @Output()
  todoAdded:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {

  }

  addItem(v){
    alert(v.value)
    this.todoAdded.emit(v);
  }
}
```

and in the parent component template:

```
<todo (todoAdded)="addTodoInList($event)"></todo>
```

Here is the content of the `addTodoInList` method:

```
addTodoInList(todo) {
  this.Todo.push(todo);
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/mQtQIXIJwMfJSfNVHvac?p=preview.